# Set The "NonSerializedAttribute" To An Auto Property

Tags: c#

This cannot be done in C#. Any way to do it?

...

*laugh*, in case my little pun wasn't understood, what I mean is: how can I mark a property in C# as NonSerialized? Of course, when the property contains logic, it's natural to be unable to do it, but Auto-Properties are serializable, and, as such, I would expect to have some way to allow me to prevent their serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit * :**
Auto Implemented Properties are backed by an anonymous field which you don't really have access to, attributes are designed to be controlled by a reflection based mechanism. These fields cannot be referenced by the reflection mechanism (because they are anonymous). This compiler feature would require a lot of changes to the generation of auto-properties... It would also require that the compiler treat auto-properties as fields for the purpose of marking field attributes onto them.

To answer the more fundamental part of the question - your point was that Auto-Properties are serialized and so there should be a way to control their serialization. You're right - but auto properties are meant as a shorthand and were never designed to give you the full flexibility, but rather to allow you to easily extend their functionality the "long" way if you ever needed it.

- I added the more details answer from my comments to the body of the answer.

Comment: I am not a C# noob ::- ). I know these things. Even so, the compiler COULD add a special check for auto-properties and allow for a NonSerialized attribute. If they are serialized, they SHOULD be marked for ignore. I know I can do it if I create setter/getters but that's another story and has nothing to do with my question ::- ).

Comment: :) 
In that case i have a better explanation for you:
Auto Implemented Properties are backed by an anonymous field which you don't really have access to, attributes are designed to be controlled by a reflection based mechanism. These fields cannot be referenced by the reflection mechanism (because they are anonymous).
Your compiler feature would require a lot of changes to the generation of auto-properties... 
It would also require that the compiler treat auto-properties as fields for the purpose of marking field attributes onto them.

Comment: I noticed that this still doesn't answer fundamental part of your question - your point was that Auto-Properties are serialized and so there should be a way to control their serialization.
You're right - but auto properties are meant as a shorthand and were never designed to give you the full flexibility, but rather to allow you to easily extend their functionality the "long" way if you ever needed it.

Comment: That is correct ::- D. After all, it boils down to me being quirky and wanting some things which would probably be clumsy to achieve. In the end, of course, I took the "long code" route and that's it. Not such a big deal. The answer, after all, is that it can't be done ::- ).

Answer (score 9):

```
  [NonSerialized]
  public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Is an error

```
  [XmlIgnore]
  public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Is not an error

> **NonSerialized** Indicates that a field of a serializable class should not be serialized.
>
> **XmlIgnore** Instructs the Serialize method of the XmlSerializer not to serialize the public field or public read/write property value

so, if you ask

> I would expect to have some way to allow me to prevent their serialization.

the answer yes, if you're using XmlSerializer

Comment: Applying `XmlIgnoreAttribute` to a property causes that property to no longer appear in generated XML documentation.

Answer (score 8):

For events, you can use `[field:NonSerialized]`, but for auto-properties this does not work.  It seems like it would be a very logical way to handle auto-properties as well, but for some reason it doesn't seem to have been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I theory yes, it's possible. In practical nope, not possible.

Serialization classes only works on private fields. When you define a auto property; at behind the scenes compiler automatically generates a private field for it. That means this is a language feature not a .net framework feature.

Also serialization classes are included in [redbits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcamer/archive/2009/08/24/red-bits-green-bits-and-net-framework-versions.aspx), which is any change prohibited due compatibility except bug fixes.

I hope thats helps.

Answer (score 0):

What was said above is right: You can't prevent an auto-implemented property from being serialized by setting an attribute like [NonSerialized]. It just does not work.

But what does work is the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute in case you are working with an WCF [DataContract]. So

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string MySecret { get; set; }
}
```

will get serialized under WCF.

Although since WCF is an opt-in technology, you can also just omit the [IgnoreDataMember] and it will work as well. So maybe my comment is a little academical ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with Mono.Cecil, a bytecode manipulation library.  Theoretically, you could add custom attributes to the hidden backing field.  This is so inconvenient, however, that I don't think it warrants an example.

If you had a large application with your own postprocessor, you might consider creating your own substitute for `NonSerializedAttribute` that could be applied to properties.  The postprocessor could then use Mono.Cecil or similar to apply `NonSerializedAttribute` to the backing fields.  It's quite common for large applications to undergo such postprocessing to save that extra bit of typing.

Answer (score -4):

`[NonSerialized] public decimal yourproperty;`

(decimal as example.)

Also remember, if you want enable your class to initialize a nonserialized member automatically, use the IDeserializationCallback interface and then implement IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization.

Comment: He said **property**.  That's a field.